# ITIN passport documents

Tags: united-states, itin

I need to apply for an ITIN from the IRS. I have a passport. Do I need to send the passport itself or can I make a copy and send the copy?

Comment: I have a lovely answer all prepared including links and excerpts from IRS instructions and FAQs. This question is answerable. I have now rewritten the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @mkennedy The question has been reopened and is ready for your answer. :)

Comment: @mkennedy - we'll be the judge of "lovely".  ;)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer which is on an unaccessible computer today so I must recreate my lovely thing. b-}

Answer (score 3):

According to the [W-7 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw7.pdf), you must send the original document or a certified copy.

A certified copy can usually be provided by the same agency that created it or some embassies and consulates can make or help you obtain certified copies. A notarized copy will not be accepted.

All quoted material is from the W-7 instructions.

> You must submit original documents, or certified copies of these
>   documents from the issuing agency, that support the information
>   provided on Form W-7. A certified document is one that the original
>   issuing agency provides and certifies as an exact copy of the original
>   document and contains an official stamped seal from the agency. You
>   may be able to request a certified copy of documents at an embassy or
>   consulate. However, services may vary between countries, so it is
>   recommended that you contact the appropriate consulate or embassy for
>   specific information.

There is a discrepancy in the instructions. Under the section for renewing an ITIN (if you don't use it for 5 years, it expires as of March 2018; prior, it was 3 years), there's another paragraph about certified copies. It states that if you are outside the US,

> Have the officers at U.S. embassies and consulates overseas provide
>   certification and authentication services. Contact the Consular
>   Section, American Citizens Services of the U.S. Embassy or Consulate
>   in advance to determine the hours of operation for these services.

Note that it says to contact the "American Citizens Services". So I don't know whether it's possible to get a certified copy from, say, a French embassy in the US for a French passport.

Finally, if you don't want to send off your original documents, you can do one of these:

1. Visit certain Taxpayer Assistance Centers

> (TACs) can verify original documentation and certified copies of the
>   documentation from the issuing agency for primary and secondary
>   applicants and their dependents. For dependents, TACs can verify
>   passports, national identification cards, and birth certificates.
>   These documents will be returned to you immediately. Service at these
>   centers is by appointment only. Appointments can be scheduled by
>   calling 1-844-545-5640.

2. Find a CAA, Certified Acceptance Agent

> A Certified Acceptance Agent (CAA) can verify original documentation
>   and certified copies of the documentation from the issuing agency for
>   primary and secondary applicants and their dependents. For dependents,
>   CAAs can only verify passports and birth certificates. The CAA will
>   return the documentation immediately after reviewing its authenticity.

There are also Acceptance Agents but they must send your documentation to the processing center.